# Component Exception Can't find variable: ratingCompleted

Tags: javascript, react-native

so i'm trying to create a rating compmonent in React-native and i used react-native-elements and it's
APIS but i keep getting this error (ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ratingCompleted)
my code

```
import { Rating, AirbnbRating } from "react-native-elements";
import { View } from 'react-native';

function Rated(props,rating) {
  const WATER_IMAGE = require("../assets/arrow.png") 

  ratingCompleted(rating);
  {
    console.log("Rating is: " + rating)
  }
  
  return (
    
<View>   
<AirbnbRating />

<AirbnbRating
  count={11}
  reviews={["Terrible", "Bad", "Meh", "OK", "Good", "Hmm...", "Very Good", "Wow", "Amazing", "Unbelievable", "Jesus"]}
  defaultRating={11}
  size={20}
/>

<Rating
  showRating
  onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted()}
  style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}
/>

<Rating
  type='heart'
  ratingCount={3}
  imageSize={60}
  showRating
  onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted()}
/>
<Rating
  type='custom'
  ratingImage={WATER_IMAGE}
  ratingColor='#3498db'
  ratingBackgroundColor='#c8c7c8'
  ratingCount={10}
  imageSize={30}
  onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted()}
  style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}
/>
    </View>
  );
}


export default Rated;
```

it would help me alot if anyone can figure this out

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after `ratingCompleted()` making it a call statement, rather than a definition of a method.

Replace it with `const ratingCompleted = () => {console.log('rating is' + rating);}`

And in your return do:

```
<Rating
  showRating
  onFinishRating={ratingCompleted}
  style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You’re using “this” in functional component ( remove it )

Change

```
ratingCompleted(rating);
  {
    console.log("Rating is: " + rating)
  }
```

To

```
ratingCompleted(rating){
    console.log("Rating is: " + rating)
}
```